# Javascript var in string

Tags: javascript

So I have this code and would like to know how I could go ahead to put my javascript var into this string. I cannot seem to make a working code for myself.

For the image source i want `picture.value` to be in there. I have tried different solutions but have not managed to work it out myself. All help is greatly appreciated

```
 var text = "<img src="">
```

I have currently been trying  `var text = "<img src=" + picture.value +">`
but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: What's the PHP? Maybe `var text = '<img src="' + picture.value + '">';`

Comment: var text = '<img src=" ' + picture.value + ' " />" ';

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `"` & `'` this together unless you escape it with a `\`.

```
 var text = '<img src="' + picture.value + '">'
```

**OR**

```
 var text = "<img src=\"" + "Hi" + "\">"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `ES6` new feature called [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (using `quote`). It is more cleaner and simpler.

```js
var picture = {'value':'test-src-location'};
var text = `<img src="${ picture.value }">`;
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `picture.value` is not empty.

```
var text = '<img src=' + picture.value + '>';
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/no293etL/

Comment: This "kind of" works, but usually it's recommended to quote the attribute values.