# Use an array index within a href

Tags: javascript, arrays, href

I have an array of links and would like to use them in a href in Javascript. e.g `array[i].link` however i'm struggling to get the correct syntax. I've tried multiple ways e.g

```
"<p>Link</p>" + '<a href="array[i].link"> + array[i].link </a>'
```

but can't get it to work. Is there a way around it?

Comment: `'<p>Link</p>' + '<a href="' + array[i].link + '">' + array[i].link </a>'`

Comment: So your question is how to do string concatenation correctly?

Comment: you have to use single quotes in javascript then concatenate the whole thing into one string

Answer (score 0):

```
 "<p>Link</p>" + "<a href='" + array[i].link + "'  </a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

`array[i].link` is not a string and therefore should be outside the `"` quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Keep `array[i].link` outside the quotation marks, i.e...

```
'<a href=' + array[i].link + '>'
```

because it's not a string literal.

Edit:

The post [JavaScript var in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035571/javascript-var-in-string) may also help answer your question